# Can you prevent mail from being sent to a specific address?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Suppose there is an email address badaddress@somedomain.com that I don't want mails to be sent to at all, either by accident or on purpose. Can I set a rule to prevent mails being send to this address? When I click the Rules button (Outlook 2013), I can only create rules for incoming messages.

Comment: See methods here: http://www.slipstick.com/how-to-outlook/prevent-sending-messages-to-wrong-email-address/